# How to run functions in the background in a Rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, background, web-crawler, mechanize

I'm crawling a website in a rake task. The basic format I have is this:

```
namespace :crawler do

  desc "TODO"
  task crawl :environment do
    Crawler.crawl!
  end

class Crawler
  require 'rubygems'
  require 'mechanize'
  def self.scrape_page!
  end

  def self.start_scrape!(link)
    # get html. prepare to scrape
  end

  def self.crawl!
    # crawl links and scrape pages
    self.delay.start_scrape(link)
  end
end
end
```

I want to scrape the links asynchronously. I looked into the delayed_jobs gem and saw that you can use the delay method on objects, but I get no output from my scraper when I use delay.

A little push in the right direction would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: use can use simple fork/exec pair to run the tasks in parallel. It works, but not so aesthetic =) and how did you use the `delayed_jobs` gem?

Comment: I just added `delayed_jobs` and the backend gem to my Gemfile, then `bundle install && rails generate delayed_job:active_record
&& rake db:migrate`

Comment: and then `Delayed::Job.enqueue Processor.new...`, yes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create new thread and call method there
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Thread.html

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I'm sure delayed_job is useful, I just don't really understand what it does.